# Ubuntu 18.0.4.3 extremely slow on Macbook Pro (Mid 2014)

Tags: 18.04, firefox, performance, macbook-pro

**After a lot of testing I found out the new linux kernel 5.0.0.x was the culprit. Re-installed 18.0.4.3 and downgraded the linux kernel to 4.18, solved the problem.**

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3 on a MacBook Pro (Retina) from Mid 2014, but the speed on which some applications run makes it impossible to work with. Especially chrome, chromium, firefox, slack (uses chromium), there's a lot of lag when typing or scrolling and it takes a very long time to load a website that uses a lot of javascript for visualizations, like a dashboard.

Booting up and running shell and other programs is quick as at should be and the other os, OSX, runs just fine.

I'd tried changing the hardware acceleration in chrome and firefox and installed [mbpfan](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704?locale=en_US) but nothing changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'd have to move back to use OSX as my default OS if there's no way to fix this. And that's something I'd like to avoid.

Below is more info on my system and some relevant output from several commands. I ran htop as well, and surely cpu usage did increase when running one of the applications, but it did not use a abnormal amount of cpu / ram.

Ubuntu is installed on the internal SSD.

[Specifications of machine](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704?locale=en_US)

**inxi -SMIG -! 31**

```
System:    Kernel: 5.0.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: MATE 1.20.1  Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Apple product: MacBookPro11 2 v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Apple model: Mac-3CBD00234E554E41 v: MacBookPro11 2 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Apple v: MBP112.88Z.0146.B00.1804111138 date: 04/11/2018
Graphics:  Card: Intel Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 2880x1800@59.99hz, 2560x1440@59.95hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8
Info:      Processes: 261 Uptime: 37 min Memory: 1660.9/15946.0MB Client: Shell (zsh) inxi: 2.3.56
```

**cat /etc/os-release**

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

**cat /proc/version**

```
 Linux version 5.0.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-046) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019
```

**glxinfo | grep render**

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
    GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
    GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_geometry_point_size,
```

**cpufreq-info** copied for 1 core

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.27 GHz.
```

**cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp**

```
30900
76000
```

**cat /proc/cpuinfo** copied for 1 core

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 70
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x1b
cpu MHz     : 3236.768
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : {REMOVED}
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs
bogomips    : 4389.96
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue. I guess you have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: The correct drivers were installed, but I have a Intel integrated graphics card. Only solution was to downgrade the kernel from 5 to 4.15.

Comment: You did this because of your graphics card? Did this improve performance? Or ist this unrelated and might improve performance for me as well?

Comment: Yes I did this because my graphic rendering was horrible using the 5.x kernel. Chrome and firefox were unusable, scrolling was so slow. If you experience the same problems and have a similar graphics card, it might help you as well.

Comment: any news about your problem?